# Creating a "Table of Contents" type Database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, documentation, documentation-generation

OK lets start at the beginning, we are at a stage that we need to create documentation for our product. And as our product is web-based, I intend to create an on-line documentation + add a copy of this on each product.

The documentation I have planned will use PHP-HTML front and Database Back-end.

So here is what im trying to structure:

```
Table of Contents
    1 Getting Started
        1.1 Hello World
        1.2 Installing
            1.2.1 Windows
            1.2.2 Unix
            1.2.3 Mac
        1.3 Configuring
            1.3.1 Windows
            1.3.2 Unix
            1.3.3 Mac
    2 Hal
        2.1 Dave
        2.2 9000
        ....
        ....
```

So HERE is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE content(
    id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    parentId VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    message TEXT NOT NULL,
    dateReg TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES `content` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

*Please forgive the syntax, this is only a mockup*

The inserts will be as follows

```
INSERT INTO content ('1', 'Getting Started', 'Hello', NULL);
INSERT INTO content ('1.1', 'Hello World', 'cout << \"Hello World\";', NULL);
.... and so on
```

The retrieval will have to done in php. The below is only making a "table of content like structure"

```
$top_query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE parentId IS NULL";
while($top_res = mysql_fetch_array($top_query)){

    print $top_res['title'] . "\n";

    $child_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE parentId={$top_res['id']}");
    while($child_res = mysql_fetch_array()){

        print $child_res['title'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

> Now i know what you will say, it needs to be recursive, yes i know, and right now lack of sleep is so bad that i cant even spell recursive (It was auto spelt by google chrome). But recursion is not my issue, i can figure that out.

**My Problem**: I cant help it think this is gona send out alot of queries, and the Database is gona have a heart attack per user accessing this document.

**The Question**: Am i on the right track, or has any one have suggestions to make this work sufficiently and be less performance intensive.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best is to cache your table of contents in a .html file instead of calling a script which will always return the same content. You just have to recreate the cache every time the table of contents is changed.

Comment: Thats a cool idea. saves performance, but still seems patched rather than solved, what if i cached the "The table of content in XML", and then just returned straight queries for the data. There fore no recursion in the live streaming

Comment: Don't worry it's a common practice, a lot of web apps use it because it's really much faster. You can cache it in XML if you prefer, the goal is just to avoid the huge performance loss if your PHP script is called every time.

Answer (score 2):

That's a typical tree structure, so just google for some solution that doesn't send dozens of queries: [google: php tree structure](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=tree+structures+php&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

[Nested Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) might be a perfect choice here as it allows you to easily retrieve the entire tree, a path to the specified node (*root -> sub -> sub -> node*) and elements had fixed positions within a tree.

Comment: php tree structure concept, is nice. but i can do that myself, thats not the issue, However i love the Nested Set concept. Thanks Plus one for it

Comment: Nested Set is definitely the way to go, if you want the benefits of recursion without multiple round trips to the database server.  Glad you picked up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation...

Would it be fair to say that the documentation is static between releases?
If so, consider caching a static copy of the complete documentation in HTML.

You could also go half way, and serialize a PHP array to file when the table of contents is updated. The display page would then just include the file, and automagically have a variable with the tree structure.